# Async Task in Windows form doesn't return result

Tags: c#, async-await

Can someone explain to me why this code doesn't work (the result is not assigned to the textbox's text property)

```
private async Task<string> NumToString(int num)
{

  return await new Task<string>(()=>{
     return  num.ToString();

     });
}
```

here is the call:

```
 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // TaskScheduler context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            var content = await NumToString(1);
          textBox1.Text = content;

        }
```

Also, If I un-comment the TaskScheduler line the click event gets fired but the NumTostring(1) doesn't fire.

Comment: Nope, there is no other code at all. The only thing I haven't done is restarting visual studio.

Comment: I have an [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that covers several common pitfalls. In particular, the `Task` constructor should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start the task, not just create it:

```
private Task<string> NumToString(int num)
{
    return Task.Run(() => num.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I knew about Task.Run() but I was trying to use the task factory. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx Task.Run() doesn't replace Task.Factory.StartNew. I am accepting your answer because your code will output the correct result. Thank you

Comment: @Servy, see my comment to max and the posted link.

Comment: @user3373870 That doesn't answer the question of why you feel the need to use a task factory here.  I see no need for it.  It's *very* rare to need that overload.  It happens, yes, but in almost all situations, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @Servy, sorry I didn't understand your question. I agree with you, however, the purpose of this 'code' is to experiment with both and I wanted to learn the proper way of using Task.Factory.StartNew if I ever need to use it

Comment: @user3373870 But you *didn't* use `StartNew`.  You used the task constructor.

Comment: This is what I used 
 await  Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
            {
            result=  num.ToString();
            }
            ),CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);